# How to Set Responsive Height of DIV in Bootstrap 3 My code attached?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, form-control

I am having problem to set responsive height of div inside bootstrap row.

In code I have bootstrap row with styling having background color. inside row I have div of full width "col xs 12". Inside this div I have div containing form control label

I have to adjust this row having background color responsive its height remain same in all devices how to set responsive height of div and row?

my code is,

```css
.big-box,
.mini-box {
    background-color: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.big-box {
    height: 69px;
    line-height: 68px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00a896, #2d6f84);">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="big-box">
             <div class="name">
                 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFullNameArabic"></asp:Label>
       </div>  
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged bootstrap-4?

Comment: :) ok I will remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give height in `vh` format like 100vh for whole page size

```css
.big-box,
.mini-box {
    background-color: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.big-box {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00a896, #2d6f84);">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="big-box">
             <div class="name">
                 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFullNameArabic"></asp:Label>
       </div>  
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help if you can tell one more thing that I am  setting label text value from code so should  I use responsive text in label via code like this : <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFullNameArabic"><p>text return from code</p></asp:Label>. It will automatically put text in label inside <p>  ?

Comment: what you want to say, i don't understand

Comment: sorry I cant not enough reputation

Comment: in my code I have label with id I will change that label text that is dynamic from code. I want that text to be responsive so should I use bootstrap <p> with font size in vw unit  as I mentioned above in my comment ?

Comment: No, you should not use `vw` unit for text, make it in `px` and use media query. Try to check https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp